# How do i convert tuples inside a list to a int interval

Tags: python

I want to make an application that will take tuples inside this list as an interval and than check if x is in any of them, than print in which one it is. I want it to do this for numbers 0 to 82 automatically

```
x = 0
z = [
    (2, 8),
    (6, 15),
    (33, 82),
    (10, 24),
    (1, 9),
    (6, 19),
    (15, 17),
    (14, 23)
]
z = [min],[max]
for x in range ([min], [max]):
    print (x, "is good")
    x =+ 1
else:
    print (x, "is not good")
```

Comment: maybe you have more than one onterval

Comment: `x in range(*(2, 8))` is probably what you're looking for. Now just loop over your list of tuples and replace `(2, 8)` with a variable.

Comment: Should lower bound be inclusive and upper exclusive (as with `range`), or both inclusive or both exclusive?

Comment: both inclusive. @tobias_k

Comment: @adamkwm i want the app to check for every x if its in any of the intervals above.

Comment: what do you mean every x? what is the range of x?

Comment: @adamkwm max x is the biggest number in the interval

Comment: I'm still confused, could you provide some example input and output? if max x is the biggest number in the interval then it must inside the interval, like 8 is biggest number in first interval (2,8) and 8 is inside (2,8).

Comment: @adamkwm correct. For example i want the program to execute 82 times since 82 times is the biggest number in my "x" list and writing 82 if's is not the solution i think. there must be some kind of other solutin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list-comprehension:

```
intervals = [
    (2, 8),
    (6, 15),
    (33, 82),
    (10, 24),
    (1, 9),
    (6, 19),
    (15, 17),
    (14, 23)
]
x = 4
possible_intervals = [inter for inter in intervals if inter[0] < x < inter[1]]
print(possible_intervals)
# [(2, 8), (1, 9)]
```

**For the first element:**

If you need only one element then we don't need to store it in a list:

```
for inter in intervals:
    if inter[0] < x < inter[1]]:
        print(interval)
        break


# Alternatively, You can define a function:
def get_match_interval(number, intervals):
    for inter in intervals:
        if inter[0] < x < inter[1]]:
            return interval
    else:
        print("No interval is matched")
  
interval = get_match_interval(4, intervals)
if interval is not None:
    print(interval)  # (2, 8)
```

Comment: FWIW: `if interval[0] < x < interval[1]`…

Comment: How do i make it that it prints only the first interval that its in

Comment: @Žan `inter = next(inter for ...)`

Comment: get the first element from the list

Comment: @deceze so this is based on what number i enter for x. What if i want the progarm to execute 82 times since 82 is the biggest number in all of the intervals?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to execute it 83 times?

```
interval_list = [
    (2, 8),
    (6, 15),
    (33, 82),
    (10, 24),
    (1, 9),
    (6, 19),
    (15, 17),
    (14, 23)
]

# in range(min,max), min is inclusive and max is exclusive so for number 0 to 82, you need range(0,83)
for x in range(0,83):
    for i in interval_list:
        if i[0] <= x <= i[1]:
            print(x, "find in", i)
            break
    else:
        print(x, "not find in list")
```

Output:

```
0 not find in list
1 find in (1, 9)
2 find in (2, 8)
3 find in (2, 8)
...
25 not find in list
26 not find in list
27 not find in list
...
80 find in (33, 82)
81 find in (33, 82)
82 find in (33, 82)
```